# Figure name with 'S' at the end

Tags: floats

I am writing supplemental material and I am trying to get Figure 1S, Figure 2S, ... ('S' ending for each Figure, indicating that this is supplemental material) instead of just Figure 1, Figure 2.

Does anyone know how to simply do that?

Comment: You are right.  I deleted my example.

Answer (score 7):

It would have been nice, if you added a MWE yourself.

You have to redefine the command, which displays the counter, which represents the figure numbers.  (Man, what a long which-which-sentence :-()  The command itself is the command `\thefigure` command.  The counter is `\figure`.

Here is a small MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}S}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  Here is a figure with S
  \caption{This is the caption}
  \label{fig:s-test}
\end{figure}

As you can see in figure~\ref{fig:s-test}, there should be a ``S'' added.

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: would't that change **all** reference numbers throughout the document?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Yes. But the question did not indicate, that the feature is needed for just a limited scope. If you need that, you can redefine the figure counter (its appearance) at a later point. Don't forget to reset the counter.

Comment: @Johannes_B thanks for clarifications, just wanted to make sure the TO knows that...

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `caption` and the `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat` command:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{XCharter} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
 \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{suppl}{#1~#2S}%
 \captionsetup[table]{labelformat=simple, singlelinecheck=off, format=mine}

\begin{document}

\captionsetup{labelformat = suppl}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{cahier}
\caption{Le cahier d’une écolière}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]